# How to create a custom delegate method like tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath method which had an arguement of tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, delegates

How to create a Custom delegate with a delegate method for a custom View with its(custom View's) object as arguement in that delegate method just like tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

**Elaboration of the question with the exact problem:**

Till now I have always used the delegate methods of different views provided in UIKit to construct views in my application. But this time I need to make a custom View but with the custom delegate and data source. I already made it. But a question always lifts. That is, whenever I need multiple same custom Views in my ViewController, then how will I recognise them seperately in my delegate methods. Definitely I need to pass the custom View's object in my delegate method as arguement. For eg.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In above delegate method, tableView object is an argument using which we can recognise the tableView if there are multiple tableViews on one ViewController and this View Controller is set as the delegate of all these tableViews.

**This is the real scenario:**

```
  //
  //  ViewController.swift
  //  DemoCustomViewDelegate
  //
  //  Created by Shubham Ojha on 4/3/16.
  //  Copyright © 2016 Shubham Ojha. All rights reserved.
  //

  import UIKit

  protocol MyCustomViewDelegate {
  func myCustomView(myCustomView: MyCustomView, didSomethingWithAString aString: String)
  }

  class MyCustomView: UIView {
  var delegate: AnyObject?
  init(frame: CGRect, andViewId viewId: String, andDelegate delegate: AnyObject) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.doSomethingWithAString(viewId)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}
func doSomethingWithAString(aString: String) {
    // do something with a string


        delegate!.myCustomView(self, didSomethingWithAString: aString)

}
}
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myView: MyCustomView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myView = MyCustomView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), andViewId: "100", andDelegate: self)
    //set the delegate
    myView.delegate = self

}
func myCustomView(myCustomView: MyCustomView, didSomethingWithAString aString: String) {
    //this delegate method is called but the object of myCustomView I need could not get
    if(myCustomView.isEqual(myView)){
        print("Got the object")//**Does not prints, this is what I actually need to print...**

    }
}

}
```

You can copy-paste the code in your ViewController and evaluate the problem.

Answers in swift are also welcome!

Answer (score 2):

is this what you mean?

```
protocol MyCustomViewDelegate {
    func myCustomView(myCustomView: MyCustomView, didSomethingWithAString aString: String)
}

class MyCustomView: UIView {
    var delegate: MyCustomViewDelegate?

    func doSomethingWithAString(aString: String) {
        // do something with a string

        // inform the delegate
        delegate?.myCustomView(self, didSomethingWithAString: aString)
    }
}
```

Comment: In - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; method the tableView object is made in the ViewController but here the myCustomView object is passed from within the MyCustomView class.

Comment: i do not understand what you mean by your comment :)

Comment: I want this MyCustomView object initialized from that ViewController which conforms to MyCustomViewDelegate, as happens in case of TableView

Comment: i see. where is the problem?

Comment: Hey Andre! Can I copy your code to paste in my question to make it more understandable, if you don't mind?

Comment: Thanks! you look talented, I want you to stick to this question until it gets solved. Please.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108087/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-shubham-ojha).

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is correct.
When in your `ViewController` you do something like

```
let myView = MyCustomView()
myView.delegate = self
```

You're telling to the `MyCustomView` object to call `self` as `delegate`.

So, when `MyCustomView` executes this code

```
delegate!.myCustomView(self, didSomethingWithAString: aString)
```

It calls this in your code

```
func myCustomView(myCustomView: MyCustomView, didSomethingWithAString aString: String) {
    //this delegate method is called but the object of myCustomView I need could not get
    if(myCustomView.isEqual(myView)){
        print("Got the object")//**Does not prints, this is what I actually need to print...**

     }
}
```

where `myCustomView` is equal to `myView`. May you should compare them by using the `==` operator instead of `isEqual`.

Comment: It returns this error, when I compare both using "==" , fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact same code? It shouldn't return an error. It shouldn't compile if so O.o

Comment: Its compiling correctly, but on runtime it throws such error.

Comment: But I used === operator, Now it runs correctly but I am not getting this printed, as it should.. print("Got the object"). That is, both the references are not equal. How should I make them equal????

Comment: Try to use `print("myCustomView: \(unsafeAddressOf(myCustomView))")` and `print("myView: \(unsafeAddressOf(myView))")` before the if condition and let's see if the address is the same

Comment: for myCustomView it printed the address, but for myView nil was printed, since I have not initialized the object in the current method. So I printed its address in the viewDidLoad method, where I initialized it. Now both the addresses are same. Its good progress. But still I have not got exact solution of the problem.

Comment: well, that's the problem. `myView` shouldn't be nil there if you want to compare them...

Comment: Let me explain you the problem. If I take multiple such custom views in my viewDidLoad method and follow the same way of delegation. How can I customize each view at my wish in my delegate method, if I am not able to recognise it?

Comment: I still don't understand what's your problem. If you're creating a lot of `MyCustomView`, you should consider to keep all the references into an array, not into a variable `myView` that can contain only one instance

Comment: No I will create multiple such variables and set each ones delegate the same ViewController.

Comment: Well I just figured out the answer, just need time to implement it. I think the myView instance must not be local to viewDidLoad, it needs to be declared as instance variable for ViewController. So its scope will remain in all the methods of the viewController and then I will be able to compare both of them. But I will upvote for you, you really helped me to reach the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look up extensions like:

```
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
// You extension to the UITableViewDelegate class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol MyCustomViewDelegate {
    func myCustomView(myCustomView: MyCustomView, didSomethingWithAString aString: String)
 }

class MyCustomView: UIView {
    var delegate: MyCustomViewDelegate?

    func doSomethingWithAString(aString: String) {
    // do something with a string

        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.myCustomView(self, didSomethingWithAString: aString)
        }
    }
}


class ViewController: UIVIewController {

    var myView: MyCustomView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myView = MyCustomView()

        //set the delegate
        myView.delegate = self

    }
}

//implement the delegate
extension ViewController: MyCustomViewDelegate {
    func myCustomView(myCustomView: MyCustomView, didSomethingWithAString aString: String) {
        //get the string from delegation
    }
}
```

Comment: In the extension the myCustomView method is not getting a call while debugging.

Comment: when are you calling 'doSomethingWithAString' from the customView? after or before you set the delegate?

Comment: I am able to call the delegate, but I am not getting the same object "myView" that I am initializing in the viewDidLoad method if(myCustomView.isEqual(myView)){
            print("Got the object")// I am not getting the object here inside the delegate method.
        }

Comment: to see if two object references point to the same object you use ===,
if myCustomView === myView {print("objects are equal")}

Comment: I have found the answer! You were right to use === operator. But the problem was that myView's reference has scope in the whole ViewController, but its object does not, since it has been initialised in the viewDidLoad(), so we cannot access it in any other method of it, if we try to do so it gives nil.